# Oauth2.0, Is it safe to store client_secret on a local storage

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using resource owner password credentials flow or password grant type. I just implemented my own authorization server using Spring Oauth2. So I wonder if it's safe to store **client_secret** on a local storage (web browser). As far as I understand **client_secret** has nothing to do with authentication it's just a thing that use to verify a client that can request for an access token (if we want to specify the only client that can request for a token). So if this client_secret is leaked the hacker would need to have valid username/password of a user anyway. There's another flow called implicit which doesn't require a client to store client_secret. Isn't that equivalent to password grant_type with poor **client_secret** storing since anyone wiht a valid username/password can request for a token anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. "Rich" clients cannot keep secrets actually secret. In your case, anyone could open browser dev tools and read the "secret".

The flows you are using are not sure neither. Use authorization-code with PKCE with public clients (those you cannot trust to keep a secret).

Comment: I have one more question so what is the worst thing that could happen if my client_secret was leaked. The hacker would need to have valid username/password anyway in order to gain access token.

Comment: Yes, the hacker won't immediately be able to access users' data, but it will give her more power to continue an attack. For example, the attacker can then find a way to intercept authorization codes and with the secret, she will be able to get access tokens. She can find a way to steal refresh tokens and then issue new access tokens using the obtained secret, etc.